# Clean up multiple file names in Linux

Tags: linux, copy, filenames

I have several fully loaded USB drives that I want to copy onto a new USB Terabyte drive.  Using a simple copy command works mostly well "cp *.* source destination"  However, some files don't get copied over because of a particular character or group of characters.

I can identify the problem files and just manually change the problematic file name but am hoping there may be some way to minimize the manual corrections.

Comment: Check out [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70785/rsyncing-files-with-special-characters-to-usb-fat32). It might prove useful. And also checkout `iconv`'s man page.

Comment: Need to consider to use ```cpio```  or ```dd``` with command line , if you use ```dd``` destination dirive will be overwritten with data from source drive , so use carefully

Comment: I should have added the following information:  The various source drives are ext4 the destination drive is FAT32.  As a result there are a number of filenames on the ext4 drives that have valid characters for ext4 but are not accepted / valid on a WIN32 formatted drive, es an example file names that include a question mark..

Comment: So ideaI solution would search and find the problem character, ex. a "?" and replace it with "_"